# my jquery functions only works just one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My code below works only once. I couldn't figure out why, please help.
i really really bad need it plz help me

> my problem : first of all plz click on the frist button from the top
>   and then click on the second one now do this all again without
>   refreshing page now u see it dosent work like the first time

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#goLeft').on('click', function() {
    if ($(".myWorks").css("opacity") == "0") {
      $('.wrap').animate({
        marginRight: '1045px'
      }, "slow");
      $('.about_me').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible");
    } else {
      $('.myWorks').toggleClass("Visibility_to_Unvisible1");
      $('.wrap').animate({
        marginRight: '1045px'
      }, "slow");
      $('.about_me').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible");
    }
  });


  $('#goRight').on('click', function() {

    if ($(".about_me").css("opacity") == "0") {
      $('.wrap').animate({
        marginRight: '20px'
      }, "slow");
      $('.myWorks').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible1");
    } else {
      $('.about_me').toggleClass("Visibility_to_Unvisible");
      $('.wrap').animate({
        marginRight: '20px'
      }, "slow");
      $('.myWorks').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible1");
    }
  });

});
```

and this is my web page : https://jsfiddle.net/nn8b8w3e/

Comment: Are you recreating/reloading the goLeft and goRight buttons ?

Comment: what do you mean it works only once ? Can you attach a fiddle for it ? where is your html ?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nn8b8w3e/

Comment: Fiddle seems to work as I would expect it to given the code. You need to be clearer about what your problem is and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @pete this is my problem :
first of all plz click on the frist button from the top and then click on the second one now do this all again without refreshing page now u see it dosent work like the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hellp friends i did it thanks for all of U this changes can fix this bug here's for U

> just Put some .css("opacity",1) , .css("opacity",0) on it

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#goLeft').on('click', function(){
    if($(".myWorks").css("opacity") == "0")
    {
       $('.wrap').animate({
      marginRight : '1045px'
    },"slow");
   $('.about_me').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible").css('opacity',1);
         }
    else {
    $('.myWorks').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible1").css('opacity',0);
    $('.wrap').animate({
     marginRight : '1045px'
    },"slow");
   $('.about_me').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible").css('opacity',1); 
    }
  });
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  $('#goRight').on('click', function(){

    if($(".about_me").css("opacity") == "0")
    {
       $('.wrap').animate({
      marginRight : '20px'
    },"slow");
   $('.myWorks').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible1").css('opacity',1);
         }
    else {
    $('.about_me').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible").css('opacity',0);
    $('.wrap').animate({
      marginRight : '20px'
    },"slow");
   $('.myWorks').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible1").css('opacity',1); 
    }
  });
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
});
```

Comment: Did you read my answer?  This is exactly what I said ... if my answer helped, pls consider accepting it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce what you're describing:

> first of all plz click on the frist button from the top and then click
>   on the second one

After clicking the first button, the second button is no longer visible to click.  Neither of the buttons on the new panel do anything.

However looking at your code, you're testing for which direction to slide, what to do, etc, based on opactiy of each panel:

```
if ($(".myWorks").css("opacity") == "0") {
```

But the code you've included never changes opacity on anything.  You assign various classes, eg:

```
$('.about_me').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible");
```

But the CSS you include does not show those classes.  You either need to define those classes with an opacity, or instead specify opacity in the action, eg:

```
$('.about_me').toggleClass("Visibility_to_visible").css('opacity', 1);
```

Comment: Or not use opacity, and test based on the elements having those classes: `if ($(".myWorks").hasClass('Visibility_to_visible') {`